# kswapd uses 100% of one core, no swap in system. Possible _raw_spin_lock kernel bug. No solution for long time

Tags: linux, memory, kernel

Sometimes kswapd0 uses 100% of one core. This issue happens during all 4.0+ kernels. drop_caches didn't work. Adding swap didn't work. There is no rule when problem appears. It can wait 1-2 weeks. It can appear twice in day. Most of times it will exist any time long, before i will reboot server. Rarely it can cure itself without reboot.

Changing power supply didn't changed anything. RAM test runned over night didn't found anything.

During my research i'm tried older kernels (some of 3.0+) - no result, problem still exists.

Some perftop outputs:

This is perftops with i915 kernel module loaded:

```
+   98,22%     0,90%  [kernel]             [k] kswapd
+   93,07%     0,32%  [kernel]             [k] shrink_zone
+   87,41%     3,71%  [kernel]             [k] shrink_slab
+   56,55%     1,11%  [i915]               [k] i915_gem_shrinker_scan
+   50,65%    46,24%  [i915]               [k] i915_gem_shrink
+   23,28%     4,32%  [kernel]             [k] super_cache_count
+   18,22%     2,33%  [kernel]             [k] list_lru_count_one
+   15,26%     0,00%  [kernel]             [k] ret_from_fork
+   15,26%     0,00%  [kernel]             [k] kthread
+   11,84%    11,83%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_lock

  46,24%  [i915]            [k] i915_gem_shrink
  12,11%  [kernel]          [k] _raw_spin_lock
   4,28%  [kernel]          [k] super_cache_count
   3,74%  [i915]            [k] i915_vma_unbind
   3,67%  [kernel]          [k] shrink_slab
   3,20%  [i915]            [k] i915_gem_object_put_pages
   2,78%  [kernel]          [k] __list_lru_count_one.isra.0
```

This is with i915 blacklisted. It don't changed this bug behavior in any way except this output:

```
    +   97,30%     2,32%  [kernel]             [k] kswapd
    +   83,40%     0,65%  [kernel]             [k] shrink_zone
    +   69,79%     7,77%  [kernel]             [k] shrink_slab
    +   59,73%    10,66%  [kernel]             [k] super_cache_count
    +   46,97%     5,76%  [kernel]             [k] list_lru_count_one
    +   30,73%    30,73%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_lock
    +   23,84%     0,00%  [kernel]             [k] ret_from_fork
    +   23,84%     0,00%  [kernel]             [k] kthread
    +    9,63%     7,23%  [kernel]             [k] __list_lru_count_one.isra.0
    +    6,18%     0,82%  [kernel]             [k] zone_balanced
    +    5,05%     2,28%  [kernel]             [k] shrink_lruvec

  30,63%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_lock
  10,84%  [kernel]             [k] super_cache_count
   7,66%  [kernel]             [k] shrink_slab
   7,28%  [kernel]             [k] __list_lru_count_one.isra.0
   5,29%  [kernel]             [k] list_lru_count_one
   3,69%  [kernel]             [k] memcg_cache_id
   3,62%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_unlock
   2,63%  [kernel]             [k] zone_watermark_ok_safe
   2,53%  [kernel]             [k] mem_cgroup_iter
   2,44%  [kernel]             [k] shrink_lruvec
   2,36%  [kernel]             [k] kswapd
   1,35%  [kernel]             [k] _raw_spin_lock
```